# Can I nest a $scope variable inside an ng-include?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-scope, angularjs-ng-include

I wanted to nest a variable inside an `ng-include`. The variable in this case would be a CDN path or file path. This works:

```
<img src="{{cdn}}uploads/avatar_{{uid}}.png" ng-src="{{cdn}}uploads/avatar_{{uid}}.png" />
```

This does not

```
<div ng-controller="expr">
  <div ng-include="'{{cdn}}logo.tpl'"></div>
</div>
```

This would really help in my template views and routes. I don't want to use directives.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`ng-include` will already evaluate whatever you pass to it so there is no need to use {{}}. This will work

```
<div ng-include="cdn + 'logo.tpl'"></div>
```

Comment: Thanks, is the across ng-bind too, I can pass JavaScript variables or $scopes in the ng-etc parameters. Shame, I like using {{ }}

Comment: it depends on the directive. Some directives like `ng-src` take a literal string. That's why if you want to add something dynamic you need to use curley braces. Other directives like `ng-include` or `ng-bind` take expressions. That's why you need the single quotes around a string you pass to ng-include. Angular will just evaluate whatever you pass it as a javascript expression.

Comment: So ng-src can include HTML and tpl files? I also notice that jQuery does not fire because those files load after.